# See if current page equals relative link - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I know that different versions of this question has been asked in the past, although this exact question has not been asked (and none of the other answers suit my purposes);*

**So, here goes**: I have a relative link in JavaScript (which is stored as a string) and I am trying to see if that string equals the current URL for the page I'm on

(*for example* if the JS link is `"/test"` and the url is `http://example.com/test` the function should return true, whereas if the string is `"/test"` and the current url is `http://example.com/derp` the function should return false).

**Lastly:**

- Hash tags in the URL should be ignored
- Get variables should also be ignored

I am looking for a function in JavaScript (or jQuery) that does this -or something that does something that gets me closer to doing this (I have to assume there is one, simply because this language (+ this framework) has so many methods for handling the URL); if there isn't one *can someone point me to a jQuery plugin that does this* or *show me a piece of custom written code* to do this (I **can't** be the first one to ask for this!)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is pertinent, but **the URL gets rewritten** (by the HTACCESS) so if you want php to end up doing anything, just take that into account

Comment: Oh, I am soooo sorry! I completely forgot to state what I've tried. Anyway, my first attempt was getting window.location and using string manipulation. Although that ended up proving wayyyy to troublesome :( SO then I googled it and came up with nothing, so I asked it here :D I was unaware of location.pathname and will try that now, my only problem is that the link string might also contain get variables and hash tags so I need a way to strip those too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
function CheckSlugValidity(slug){
    return slug.indexOf(window.location.pathname) == 0;
}
```

Call it like

```
CheckSlugValidity("/test");
```

Comment: Like I said in the comment to my question, I think this would work if the get variables and hash could be removed from the slug. What if we did this by only reading what was in the slug before the first instance of a question mark/hash tag. I'm unsure of how we would do that though....

Comment: var windowUrl = window.location;
    windowUrl = windowUrl.indexOf('#') > -1 ? windowUrl.substring(0, windowUrl.indexOf('#')) : windowUrl;
    windowUrl = windowUrl.indexOf('?') > -1 ? windowUrl.substring(0, windowUrl.indexOf('?')) : windowUrl;

That should remove hash tags and get params

Comment: heh good call naveen. curious, how is window.location.pathname different from window.location.href or even just window.location?

Answer (score 1):

This works in my testing in a few sites:

```
var fragment = '/test'; // assuming there's a slash at the front as you mention

var url = window.location.href.split('/');
var last_item = '/' + url[url.length-1];
last_item = last_item.replace(/(\?|\#).*/, '');

last_item == fragment ? alert('match') : alert('not a match');
```

**UPDATE:**
Updated to strip out query strings starting with '?' or hashes (#)

Good catch, updated below:

```
var fragment = '/testtabs/test/url_test.html';
var url = window.location.pathname;

url == fragment ? alert('match') : alert('not a match');
```

[Tested here](http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/test/url_test.html?test=hi)

Comment: I am no string manipulation guru, but won't that break if the site is `Http://example.com/foo/test`?

Comment: I'm trying it here (http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/test/url_test.html) and here (http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/url_test.html) and it works equally well there.

Comment: Just to be sure, tried http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/test/foo/url_test.html and that works too

Comment: Try it with the fragment having extra slashes in it (for example `/test/foo`) That should break it because this code only compares the last parts of the urls

Comment: Yes, because you are still only matching the last part of the URL (so in short `fragment = '/test'` should *only* match `bjornthomson.com/test`)

Comment: Thanks, good catch. Hopefully the updated answer fixes the issue.